# Twitter Bootstrap: changed navbar collapse threshold, side-effect on drop-downs

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, media-queries

I am using `Twitter Bootstrap 2.1.1` and use navbar collapse and navbar dropdowns similar to this example on [Twitter Bootstrap Github page](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/examples/hero.html)

I know that it collapses at 979px and expands at 980px, and I went and changed it to collapse at 779px, based on the **accepted answer** to:

[How to change navbar collapse threshold using Twitter bootstrap-responsive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9405610/how-to-change-navbar-collapse-threshold-using-twitter-bootstrap-responsive)

I modified **bootstrap.responsive.css**

```
@media (max-width: 979px) {...}
```

to

```
@media (max-width: 779px) {...}
```

Works great, and I see that the navbar now collapses at 779px and expands at 780px.

However, I am seeing a side effect.

When I resize my browser to have a width between 780px and 979px (a range where the navbar is no longer collapsed) and I click on a drop-down, it won't render the drop-down options.  If I resize to 980px or wider, then I see the drop-down options.

I am using Firefox Firesizer, so I can watch the width.  In fact, if I click on a drop-down and then drag the window size, I can see it draw the drop-down options right at 980px and then they disappear when I go under 979px.

Has anyone come across this before?

I suspect there is some other Media Query for the dropdown-menu (or its related classes) that would need to be changed when changing the navbar collapse threshold.  However, I have not been able to figure out a solution.  I would be very grateful for any help, insight, or recommendations.  Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Late to the party, but for posterity sake:

When resizing the navbar you need to adjust / overwrite two items in the `bootstrap-responsive.css` file.

- `@media (max-width: 979px)` => `@media (max-width: 1120px)`

AND:

- `@media (max-width: 780px)` => `@media (max-width: 1121px)`

(`1120px` is the threshold for navbar collapse)

see more: https://gist.github.com/4269590