# Change Bootstrap css in Html Inline Styles

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, stylesheet

I am using Bootstrap 3.2.0. I am using a navbar ofered by Bootstrap. I have too many links in the navbar. If I resize the window, the links are listed downward. And the menu icon appears if the window is small enough (decided by Bootstrap css). I want that menu icon appear more earlier, before the links expand to downward. However, I do not want to edit the css file. Am I able to get this functionality done in the html code by using inline styles or Internal Style Sheet. I hope the question is clear.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you please post some example on jsfiddle or codepen, or post some code in your question and show what you have tried?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to change navbar collapse threshold using Twitter bootstrap-responsive?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9405610/how-to-change-navbar-collapse-threshold-using-twitter-bootstrap-responsive)

Comment: I do not have a specific code. I think my question does not need any code. Is it not clear?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible to do this in HTML.  You would need to change the media query in you CSS stylesheet.  Alternatively, you can put your CSS *directly in your HTML* with the `<style>` tag, and use the !important command on your media query.  (*Please* don't use `!important` unless you **really have to**).

Hope this helps!